# Union type with Record<string, never> allows any key to be accessed in object

Tags: typescript, types

I have a value (that I can't change) that can be either a user object with well defined key types, or an empty object: `{}`.

When trying to type that value, what I have is basically:

`type StateUser = User | Record<string, never>`

The reason I'm using `Record<string, never>` is because it's recommended by `@typescript-eslint/ban-types`:

```
Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".
- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `object` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "empty object", you probably want `Record<string, never>` instead
```

But when trying to read from my value, TS is ignoring the `Record<string, never>` and just considering the type as if it was just User:

```
const getRole = (user: StateUser) => user.role.toUpperCase();
```

TS allows this, what I expected was that, when trying to access the `role` key, TS would throw an error like:

`` Property 'role' does not exist on type `User | Record<string, never>'. ``

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Record types can hold any key, so there's no discriminant. If the function returns different types based on the argument types you could use an overload.

Comment: @JaredSmith
>Record types can hold any key, so there's no discriminant

Yeah, but shouldn't role have a type like: `User["role"] | never`? That's what I'm trying to avoid. `toUpperCase()` will error on runtime. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: `User["role"] | never` is the same as `User["role"]`. `never` is the empty set, so if you add it to a set, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You probably want `Record<never, never>` instead: https://tsplay.dev/N95AJN

Comment: @zenly, hmm, your point makes sense. I'm guessing then that `Record<string, unknown>` would be closer to what I was looking for then, because the resulting union would involve an unknown that will have the opposite behavior of never, and not allow anything. 

I remember trying `Record<never, never>`, but having some issue with it, but now it seems to work. My implementation has changed a bit since I wrote the question, so maybe that's why.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @zenly on a comment, the behavior I'm seeing is being caused by the resulting union of `User["role"] | never` being equivalent to just `User["role"]`. This seems to imply that Eslint's instructions are misleading, since that's obviously not the behavior one would expect of accessing the keys of an empty object `{}`.

Two alternative ways of reaching the desired result are:

`Record<never, never>` or `object`.

Notice that this solution only works for blocking reading of the value, not assignment. Any kind of object can be assigned to the union type. A solution that blocks assignment is something like:

```
type EmptyObject = Record<string, never> | Record<"", never>
```

Where the `""` is just any specific key, that won't be assignable anyway because it's value is never. Although this has other implications, such that it won't be assignable to `Partial<Something>`, even though for `const x = {}`, x can be assigned to any `Partial` type. In my particular use case, the best solution ended up being just going with `object`, because assignment is not as much of an issue.